Airflow Workers (Celery) CPU usage problem on K8S
I am experiencing a problem with CPU resource allocation for worker pods on Kubernetes. Currently, I am migrating Airflow from an EC2 instance to Kubernetes. The EC2 instance has 4 CPUs, and the Celery worker_concurrency configuration is set to 16, which is the default setting. However, when running on Kubernetes, I need to set the pod worker_concurrency to 4 because each worker concurrency requires 1 CPU. For instance, if I use the default 16 workers, it would consume 16 CPUs on Kubernetes.
My question is: Why is an EC2 instance with 4 CPUs able to manage 16 concurrent workers running simultaneously, while a Kubernetes pod requires an unreasonable amount of CPUs for the same configuration?
Currently, I am running 2 pods with 4 concurrent workers each, using a total of 8 workers (Only 8 tasks is on running status). At full load, my resources look like this:

If I set the concurrency to 16 on Kubernetes, all tasks are failing with the following error in the logs (reaching the max CPU limit per pod: ~6):
`*** Could not read served logs: Request URL is missing an 'http://' or 'https://' protocol.`
I also tried setting the CPU limit to 6 and other values, but it didn't help.
Thank you for your assistance.

Are you setting cpu limits (reservations) on the tasks for Kubernetes?

Also, what is your ‘remote_base_log_folder’ setting in the airflow config (under logging) https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/logging-monitoring/logging-tasks.html

Have you set up a persistent volume for logs? https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/8.3.1/kubernetes_executor.html#managing-dags-and-logs

Yes, i have set remote logging (all logs going into GCP bucket) and reservations, limits for CPU.  If i change executor into KubernetesExecutor - everything works. I think its celery configuration problem, but i use default settings and it hits by max cpu - 4.
